# API call for each using JS

Tags: javascript, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google API and JS click outside to convert the first input into targeted language.

I want to convert into multiple language from first input, I have added another Targeted language as URDU.

I need in such a way, when I give input in first box, it gets converted into Spanish as well as Urdu.

```js
let $ = el => document.querySelector(el);

$('#input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var text = this.value;
  doGet(text);
}, false);

function doGet(txt) {
  var sourceText = txt;  
  var sourceLang = 'en';
  var targetLang = $(".targee").value;
    
  var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" 
            + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);
  
  $('.translated').value = 'LOADING...';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      let finaltext = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        finaltext += data[0][i][0];
      }
      $('.translated').value = finaltext;
    }
  };
  request.send();
}
```

```css
h2, h3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
  width: 40%;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 160px;
  margin: 5px auto 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  resize: none;
  
  &:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
    outline: none;
  }
}
.btn-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <input id="input">
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Spanish</h2>
      <input value="es" class="targee">
      <input id="es" class="translated">
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Urdu</h2>
      <input value="ur" class="targee">
      <input id="ur" class="translated">
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: If you want to translate the text into multiple languages, you need to make multiple API calls for each target language. You can modify your code to make two API calls, one for Spanish and one for Urdu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the google translate API for multi-languages, you can loop the request to the API URL. To avoid errors in data synchronization, you can use Javascript `Promise` and async function.

```js
let $ = el => document.querySelector(el);
let $$ = el => document.querySelectorAll(el);

$('#input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var text = this.value;
  doGet(text);
}, false);

async function doGet(txt) {
  var sourceText = txt;  
  var sourceLang = 'en';
  var targetLangs = $$(".targee");
  var request;
  var url; 
  
  for(var j = 0; j < targetLangs.length; j++) {
    url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" 
            + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLangs[j].value + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);
    $$('.translated')[j].value = 'LOADING...';
    $$('.translated')[j].value = await translate(url);
  }
}

async function translate(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);

    request.onload = () => {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if(data[0]) {
          let finaltext = '';
          for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            finaltext += data[0][i][0];
          };
          resolve(finaltext);
        } else {
          resolve('');
        }
      } else {
        // Error!
        reject("error: "+request.statusText);
      }
    };
    request.send();
  });
}
```

```css
h2, h3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
  width: 40%;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 160px;
  margin: 5px auto 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  resize: none;
  
  &:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
    outline: none;
  }
}
.btn-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <input id="input">
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Spanish</h2>
      <input value="es" class="targee">
      <input id="es" class="translated">
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Urdu</h2>
      <input value="ur" class="targee">
      <input id="ur" class="translated">
    </div>
  
  </div>
```